# JAVA Webservice SOAP Client How to set xmlns method attribute?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I implemented a soap client to call a web service method of a third person. The method is: InsertData_Str

I've a problem with my java application. I need to add to the InsertData_Str method the xmlns attribute but it doesn't work, it put an empty value and I don't understand why. Any idea?

Here is the code:

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");
soapMessage.setContentDescription("MY Connector");

SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

String serverURI = "http://www.ik.com/ikConnect";

// SOAP Envelope
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

envelope.setPrefix("soap");
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

SOAPElement soapMethod = soapBody.addChildElement("InsertData_Str"); //Method
//soapMethod.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.ik.com/ikConnect"); //This doesn't work
QName attributeName = new QName("xmlns");
soapMethod.addAttribute(attributeName,"http://www.ik.com/ikConnect"); //If I Debugg I can see that xmln attribute is OK but when the message is sent xmln is empty
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><InsertData_Str xmlns=""><xdoc xmlns="http://www.ik.com/ikConnect">TEST</xdoc></InsertData_Str></SOAP-ENV:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I changed SOAPElement addChildElement(String localName) method by this other one addChildElement(String localName,String prefix,String uri)

Example:

```
String serverURI = "http://www.ik.com/ikConnect";
SOAPElement soapMethod = soapBody.addChildElement("InsertData_Str", "", serverURI);
```